# multiple ajax calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax

i am trying to set up two serial ajax calls in angular js. In the first step i am geting object data in this format:

```
{
"kname": "Hilton Hotel",
"kaddress": "Sch\u00f6neberger Str. 2-4",
"kcity": "Berlin",
"kfon": "069 7147 2214",      
"url":"assets/testKontietung.json"
}
```

In the second step I am taking the url from the object and make one more ajax call with it. In this example: `"url":"assets/testKontietung.json"`

Question: how do i set up the second dynamic call? How do i set up dynamic url in `$http.get`?

Comment: The question is trivial

Comment: Special thanks to Alexander Elgin! your opinion was very important and helped a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the second ajax call in the promise for the first call in the following way:

```
$http.get('first_url').then(function(data) {
    var second_url = data.url;
    $http.get(second_url).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //final data
    })
})
```

Comment: @Pedro, did you find the answer helpful?

Comment: You can also chain your promises. If you first `return second_url` you can add a second `then()` after the first `then()`. This way you get a flatter, more readable structure to your code. I also means that you don't have to handle rejected promises until you reach the very end of the promise chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some event to make another AJAX call..
And you can differentiate the calls by a parameter, say page.. Increment the page of page every time that event is triggered.

for e.g on a click of button

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="getJSON()" />
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getJSON = function(){

$http.get(url,{})
     .success(function(data){  
              $http.get(data.url,{})
              .success(function(data){  });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http.post('your/url',data)
      .success(function(data){
      var nexturl = data.url;
      if(nexturl){
       $http.get('' + nexturl)
       .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    }
    })
```